# Is it possible to make a JAR file for a Java Applet?

Tags: java, jar, applet

Is it possible to make a JAR file for a Java Applet? And no, I don't have a JApplet, I have an Applet. My class extends Applet instead of JApplet.

Comment: Why don't you try by deploying one and thereby posting answer to your own question! Give it a try!

Comment: I did and nothing worked :( That's why I'm asking you guys.

Comment: *"Is it possible to make a JAR file for a Java Applet?"*  It is not only possible, but now that code basically *has* to be digitally signed, it is effectively compulsory.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**. See [Deploying An Applet In Under 10 Minutes](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/deploying_an_applet_in_under) :

- Compile / build your applet's Java code and make sure all class
  files and resources such as images etc. are in a separate directory,
  example build/components.
- Create a jar file containing your applet's
  class files and resources.
- Sign your jar file if the applet needs
  special security permissions, for example, to be launched in a modern JRE with default settings. By default, unsigned code will be blocked.
- Create a JNLP file that describes how your applet
  should be launched.

See also [Deployment Toolkit 101 - Java Tutorials Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/deployment_toolkit_101)

Comment: Oh shoot, it seems to be that they deleted the Deployment Toolkit 101.

Comment: They just moved it :)

Comment: *"Sign your jar file if the applet needs special security permissions, for example,.."*  ..to be launched in a modern JRE with default settings.  By default, unsigned code will be blocked.